# Nginx: SNI doesn't work for server_name with multiple arguments

Tags: nginx, ssl, sni

With this Nginx config:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.x.nl x.nl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/x.nl.crtkeyca;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/x.nl.crtkeyca;

    [...]

}
```

This works:

```
openssl s_client -servername www.x.nl -connect localhost:443 < /dev/null
```

This doesn't, as I get the default vhost CN:

```
openssl s_client -servername x.nl -connect localhost:443 < /dev/null
```

Am using stock Nginx from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, unfortunately very old (1.1.19).

Is it supposed to work in newer versions or do I require to duplicate my `server {}` definitions?

Comment: I'm using such setup successfully with nginx 1.4.6.

Comment: That should work. Does your certificate really contains both names?

Comment: What does *This doesn't* mean exactly?

Comment: Yes, the cert contains both names. And _this doesn't_ means that I get the certificate from the default vhost/server block.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue with Nginx 1.8.0.

In my case, this issue fixes setup different name in ssl_session_cache (see "???"):

```
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL_???:10m;
```

Comment: Hi Jan, I've experienced the same thing on nginx 1.8.0 

Do you mean to add  `ssl_session_cache shared:SSL_differentName:10m;` on each `http` block?

Comment: Hi Erwin, yes, exactly :-) Btw, now i use latest Nginx 1.9.3.